# An example of constrained system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics, poisson-brackets

I have this homework on an analysis of a constrained Hamiltonian system and I need some help with the following problem. The system is described using Darboux coordinates and a specific Hamiltonian:

Consider a Hamiltonian system with the following Darboux coordinates: $\{P_N, N; P_\mu, X^\mu\}$ where $\mu : 0, 1, 2$. In these coordinates, let the Hamiltonian be:

$$ H = \frac{N}{2} P^2 - \frac{N}{2} (X^2 - R^2), \tag{1} $$

where $P^2 := \eta_{\mu\nu} P^\mu P^\nu$ (similarly for $X^2$), and $\eta$ is the three-dimensional Minkowski metric. Note that in the Darboux coordinates, the symplectic form is:

$$ \omega = dP_N \wedge dN + dP_\mu \wedge dX^\mu. \tag{3} $$

(a) Show that rotations and boosts are local infinitesimal symmetries of the system while translations are not. (Recall that a local infinitesimal symmetry is a Hamiltonian vector field belonging to a scalar that has zero Poisson bracket with $H$.)

(b) Now assume we put the constraints $C_1 = P_N = 0$ and $C_2 = P^2 - (X^2 - R^2)^2 = 0$ on the system. Discuss whether these constraints are first-class or second-class. Find if “consistency” of these constraints produce new constraints. (i.e., Show whether $\{C_{1,2}, H\}$ is zero on the constraint surface.)

(c) Show that on the constraint surface $S$ such that $C_1 = 0$ and $C_2 = 0$, the Hamiltonian vector fields $X_{C_1}$ and $X_{C_2}$ are degenerate directions of the symplectic form pulled back to the surface. (Suggestion: choose a new coordinate system $y^\alpha$ such that the constraint surface corresponds to $y^0 = 0$ and $y^1 = 0$.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.